# Почему программа получает предупреждение? com.github.sardine.impl.io.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream close WARNING: Abort connection

Tags: java, webdav

Класс

```
public class Skachivaniye {
    public void Skachivaniye(String AdresProgrammServera, String AdresProgrammKliyenta) {
        try {
            Sardine Sardina = SardineFactory.begin("login", "password");
            InputStream VkhodnoyPotok = Sardina.get("https://webdav.yandex.ru" + AdresProgrammServera);
            File Fayl = new File(AdresProgrammKliyenta);
            OutputStream VykhodnoyPotok = new FileOutputStream(Fayl);
            byte[] Bufer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int ChteniyeBufrea;

            while((ChteniyeBufrea = VkhodnoyPotok.read(Bufer)) != -1) {
                VykhodnoyPotok.write(Bufer, 0, ChteniyeBufrea);
            }

            VkhodnoyPotok.close();
            VykhodnoyPotok.close();
            out.println("\n\n            Скачано");
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException Isklyucheniye) {
            out.println("\n\n            Ошибка");
            out.println("\n                " + Isklyucheniye.getMessage());
        }

        catch(IOException Isklyucheniye) {
            out.println("\n\n            Ошибка");
            out.println("\n                " + Isklyucheniye.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов класса

```
Skachivaniye Skachivaniye = new Skachivaniye();
out.print("\n        Авест");
Skachivaniye.Skachivaniye("/" + "Скрипты%2C%20Сверка%20и%20Avest" + "/" + "Avest.zip", AdresProgramm.AdresProgramm + "\\" + "Avest.zip");
out.print("\n        Формирование");
Skachivaniye.Skachivaniye("/" + ObyektProgram.Obyekt1 + "/" + ObyektProgram.Obyekt2.replaceAll(" ", "%20") + ".zip", AdresProgramm.AdresProgramm  + "\\" + ObyektProgram.Obyekt2.replaceAll("%20", " ") + ".zip");
out.print("\n        Сверка");
Skachivaniye.Skachivaniye("/" + "Скрипты%2C%20Сверка%20и%20Avest" + "/" + "Сверка%20ЭСЧФ.zip", AdresProgramm.AdresProgramm + "\\" + "Сверка ЭСЧФ.zip");
out.print("\n        Инструкции");
Skachivaniye.Skachivaniye("/" + "Скрипты%2C%20Сверка%20и%20Avest" + "/" + "Инструкция%20по%20работе%20с%20ЭСЧФ.doc", AdresProgramm.AdresProgramm + "\\" + "Инструкция по работе с ЭСЧФ.doc");
Skachivaniye.Skachivaniye("/" + "Скрипты%2C%20Сверка%20и%20Avest" + "/" + "Установка%20(если%20ничего%20установлено%20не%20было).txt", AdresProgramm.AdresProgramm + "\\" + "Установка (если ничего установлено не было).txt");
```

Консоль

> Скачивание
>
> Авест
>
> Скачано
>
> Формирование
>
> Скачано
>
> Сверка
>
> Скачано
>
> Инструкциимар 14, 2017 10:58:45 AM
>   com.github.sardine.impl.io.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream close WARNING:
>   Abort connection for response HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   [Yandex-Cloud-Request-ID: dav-NQs7_13B_6EZ-2-webdav8o,
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Server:
>   MochiWeb/1.0, Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 07:24:03 GMT,
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=300, Etag: b995cc623edcfe7884425af925fa4aa1, Date:
>   Tue, 14 Mar 2017 07:58:35 GMT, Content-Type: application/msword,
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%A7%D0%A4.doc",
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes]
>   org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity@59d016c9}
>
> Скачано
>
> Скачано

Почему я получаю это предупреждение и как его убрать? Файлы качаются.

Код из класса

```
if (log.isLoggable(Level.WARNING))
            {
                log.warning(String.format("Abort connection for response %s", response));
            }
            // Close an HTTP response as quickly as possible, avoiding consuming
            // response data unnecessarily though at the expense of making underlying
            // connections unavailable for reuse.
            // The response proxy will force close the connection.
            ((CloseableHttpResponse) response).close();
```

Comment: >Почему я получаю это предупреждение -> Просто у компилятора глаза кровоточат от таких названий ))

Comment: @AndrewGrow ???

Comment: @ELe просто не все понятно из твоего кода, но судя по предупреждению, "копай" в сторону класса Sardine. И думаю тебе стоит почитать [JCC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков Может можно не показывать его?

Comment: @ELe Попробуйте перед классом добавить аннотацию `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: @Евгений Как исправить вы не знаете, да?

Comment: @ELe класс Sardine ты писал, или это сторонняя библиотека?

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков Сторонняя библиотека

Comment: @ELe ты видимо не закрываешь соединение с сервером, вот и возникает предупреждение

Comment: @Евгений тупиков Только на 4 файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил версию Sardine в Maven с 5.7 на 5.6 и предупреждение больше не получаю.